# Serialized Error while running multiple test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing

Im running multiple tests using `npm run test` and got this error:

```
Vitest caught 2 unhandled errors during the test run.
This might cause false positive tests. Resolve unhandled errors to make sure your tests are not affected.

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Uncaught Exception ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
 ❯ Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] node:net:1740:16
 ❯ listenInCluster node:net:1788:12
 ❯ Server.listen node:net:1876:7
 ❯ Function.listen node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24
 ❯ src/server.js:93:5
     91| });
     92| 
     93| app.listen(port, () => {
       |     ^
     94|   console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
     95| });
 ❯ VitestExecutor.directRequest node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:331:11
 ❯ VitestExecutor.cachedRequest node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:171:14
 ❯ VitestExecutor.dependencyRequest node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:220:14
 ❯ src/api/controllers/__test__/statistics.test.js:3:31
 ❯ VitestExecutor.directRequest node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:331:5
```

This is my normalizePort in server.js

```
const DEFAULT_PORT = 3001;

let port = process.env.PORT || DEFAULT_PORT;

// Start the server
// Override the port for testing
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
}
```

Im confused that do I need to create different ports for each test file? Or did I setup the normalize port incorrectly here?

I searched a bunch but haven't found a proper solution for this. Any helps would be appreciated for setting the testing server.